# It it possible to break from foreachline

Tags: kotlin

is it possible to break from foreachline. my code :

```
       fun test() {
        bufferedReader.forEachLine {
            val nameParam = it.split(":")[0]
            if (name == "test")
                return // here i wan to return from function
        }
    }
```

I've tried 'return@foreachline' but it just continue to next line

Comment: You can use `return@forEachLine`

Comment: what do you want to do if "test" never appears? Continue on with more logic, or are you just trying to see if it contains "test"?

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not: non-local returns are only supported for [inline functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html), and [`forEachLine { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/for-each-line.html) is not an inline one, so you can only use `return@forEachLine` that exits the lambda.

An alternative that allows it is to read the lines first and then iterate over them:

```
bufferedReader.lines().use { lines ->
    for (it in lines) {
        val nameParam = it.split(":")[0]
        if (name == "test")
            break
    }
}
```

<sup>Here, [`.use { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html) ensures that the lazy `Stream` created by `.lines()` is closed once it is not needed anymore.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Break and continue for custom control structures are not implemented yet.
You could use `println()`.

Answer (score 0):

The following simple hack works perfectly fine:

```
 val fileToScann = File("file.txt")
        fileToScan.forEachLine {
            if( it.contains("12345") ) {
                throw Exception("line found:"+it)
            }
        }
        throw Exception("line not found")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use iterator and `run{}` block to exit from `forEach`.

```
var hasTestLine = false
textFile.bufferedReader().use { reader ->
    run {
        reader.lineSequence().iterator().forEach { line ->
            if (line == "test") {
                hasTestLine = true
                return@run
            }
        }
    }
}
```